# predictions with random forest in caret

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, caret

I recently got confused on how to do correct predictions for random forrests. 
Here is an example:

```
library(caret)
n <- nrow(iris)
set.seed(44)
train_idx = sample(1:n, 0.8*n, replace = F)

traindat = iris[train_idx,]
testdat = iris[-train_idx,]


control  <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
tunegrid <- expand.grid(mtry = 1:3)

rf <- train(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = traindat, trControl = control, tuneGrid = tunegrid)
```

So basically I run a simple random forest to predict Sepal.Length. Now

```
> print(rf)
Random Forest 

120 samples
  4 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 107, 108, 107, 108, 106, 108, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  RMSE       Rsquared   MAE      
  1     0.4121244  0.8035960  0.3294848
  2     0.3466976  0.8485902  0.2917225
  3     0.3340895  0.8547870  0.2811055

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 3.
```

This tells me that the parameter mtry = 3 performed best on the training set with a RMSE of 0.33. I went on to check for this RMSEa and tried to calculate it by hand:

```
> sqrt(mean((predict.train(rf, newdata = traindat, type = "raw") - traindat$Sepal.Length)^2))
[1] 0.1736768
```

What did I do wrong? Is predict.train the right way to do predictions for random forests?

Glad to hear your advice.
Thank you.

Comment: The RMSE values shown in the printed model output represent the 'model performance on the hold-out sample' (or 'hold-out validation set') of the cross-validation runs. Many research papers in recent years have reported only this hold-out sample RMSE without testing set performance - but only if no model tuning had been performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation of `train` and `trainControl`, there is a sampling / cross-validation process which separates your training set into a "sub-training" set and a "sub-validation" set to build the model.

Default value for separation is `0.75`, which means that at each iteration of the cross-validation, 75% of your values are used to build the sub-training set and the remaining 25% (sub-testing set) are tested. So the RMSE displayed in `rf` is the RMSE calculated on the sub-testing sets, based on the model built with the sub-validation sets (hence, distinct datasets for training and testing).

Obviously, the final model uses all your data with the optimal calculated parameters - in your case, `mtry = 3`. So when your are predicting your `traindat` with the final `rf` model and calculating the resulting RMSE, you are not comparing the same things. You get a lower RMSE because the data your are predicting is present in the model you have constructed, whereas it was not the case when `train` evaluated the performance of the models.

If you want to get the partition of your folds, set `savePredictions` parameter in your `trainControl` to `TRUE` or `"all"`.

```
control  <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, savePredictions = T)
```

You can then access to the partition through your `train` object, using `pred` element.

```
> head(rf$pred)
        pred obs rowIndex mtry    Resample
  1 5.766016 5.6        7    1 Fold01.Rep1
  2 5.732148 5.7       28    1 Fold01.Rep1
  3 4.939007 4.3       34    1 Fold01.Rep1
  4 5.002672 4.8       48    1 Fold01.Rep1
  5 6.756495 7.7       71    1 Fold01.Rep1
  6 6.354641 6.7       74    1 Fold01.Rep1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer:
is there any way to see the predicted values of each of the sub-validation sets? 
If I am not mistaken, every row in the original tainingdata set is in a sub-validation set exactly three times and I would like to know the corresponding predictions.

Comment: Set `savePredictions` parameter in `trainControl` to `T` or `(all)`. I will edit my answer to include this part.